# Removing hyphens in SQLCMD

Tags: bash, sqlcmd

Is that a way to remove dashed line --------- in SQL cmd. E.g:

```
Name  ID
--------
Alex  13
Alice 22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a best solution:

(1)Get the column headers

```
sqlcmd -S DEV\SQLEXPRESS -d www -U dbadmin -P Admin123$ -Q "set nocount on;select top 0 * from dbo.www1" -o "C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\20.csv" -s "|"
```

(2)Remove hyphen line

```
findstr /R /C:"^[^-]*$" C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\20.csv > C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\21.csv
```

(3)Get data without headers

```
sqlcmd -S DEV\SQLEXPRESS -d www -U dbadmin -P Admin123$ -i "C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\12.sql" -s "|" -h -1 -o "C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\22.csv"
```

(4)Append header and data

```
type C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\21.csv C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\22.csv > C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\23.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can stop the `sqlcmd` to give you the result in that form. All you can do is post-process it to remove the line containing hyphens. Like:

`sqlcmd ... | sed -e '2d'`

Comment: Is it like this sqlcmd -S DEV\SQLEXPRESS -d Dsia -U dbadmin -P Admin123$ -i "C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\12.sql" -s "|" -o "C:\export-sql-server-to-csv\output15.csv" | sed -e '2d'

Answer (score 0):

These two steps will get you the table extract in a .csv file with no hyphen and no row counts. (Tried and Tested)

1. Output columns with headers (this will have the hyphens in the o/p file)
   **sqlcmd -S YourServer -Q "set nocount on;select columnnames from YourDB.YourSchema.TheTableOrView" -o "Extract.csv" -s "," -W 700**
2. Strip the ---'s from this file and get the expected format in the newly created csv file.
   **findstr /R /C:"^[^-]*$" Extract.csv > Extract1.csv**